# как получить аудио фаил с сайта с помощью playwright python. Скачать по ссылки из html не возможно, нету прав

Tags: python, playwright

```
async def in_valid(nomeras):                                                                
        async with async_playwright() as p:
            browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
            page = await browser.new_page()
            await page.goto()
            await page.get_by_label().click()
            await page.get_by_label().fill(nomeras)
            await page.get_by_role("button", name="Продолжить").click()
            if "" in await page.content():
                await page.get_by_role("button", name="Прослушать").click()
                #!!!!!!! нужно получить и сохранить аудио
                await page.get_by_text("").click()
                await page.get_by_label("Введите код с картинки").fill(negr)
                await page.get_by_role("button", name="Продолжить").click()
                if "" in await page.content():
                    return 
                else:
                    return 
            await browser.close()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.